# How to positioning elements with CSS flexbox?

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I have this code:

```css
.top-row,
.bottom-row {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.box1,
.box2,
.box3,
.box4 {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}

.header {
  background: tan;
  padding: 10px;
}

.column1 {
  background: pink;
  padding: 10px;
}

.column2 {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-row">
  <div class="box1">
    <div class="header">
      <!-- this field should be left -->
      <form>
        <input type="text">
      </form>
      <!-- this button should be left -->
      <button class="add">+</button>
      <!-- this button should be right -->
      <button class="edit">edit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column1">
      left column
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      right column
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <div class="header">
      <!-- this button should be left -->
      <button class="add">+</button>
      <!-- these buttons should be centered -->
      <button class="edit">btn1</button>
      <button class="edit">btn2</button>
      <button class="edit">btn3</button>
      <!-- this field should be right -->
      <form>
        <input type="text">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="column1">
      left column
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      right column
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-row">
  <div class="box3">
    <div class="header">
      header
    </div>
    <div class="column1">
      left column
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      right column
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box4">
    <div class="header">
      header
    </div>
    <div class="column1">
      left column
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      right column
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have made this codepen:
https://codepen.io/demiurgen/pen/zzygRb

I need help to get the `left` and `right` columns to be left and right columns.
They should take up `50%` of the space inside their box. Each box is supposed to be a two column layout with a header spanning the top.

Also, how do I position elements like form fields and buttons whit in a flexbox?
Do I need to make another flexbox child for every element I want to position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have nested flex-containers to achieve desired layout. You can use `flex: 0 0 50%` to make element `50%` width and don't allow element to grow and shrink. Note that `flex` is shorthand for setting `flex-grow`, `flow-shrink` and `flex-basis`.

Also this can be achieved via setting `flex: 1 0 0`. This is forcing element to grow but don't grow based on content (default value is: `flex: 0 1 auto`, where  `auto` means take `width` based on content).

Demo:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* new */
}

.top-row,
.bottom-row {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.box1,
.box2,
.box3,
.box4 {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
  
  display: flex; /* new */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* new */
}

.header {
  background: tan;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 0 0 100%; /* new */
}

.column1 {
  background: pink;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 0 0 50%; /* new */
}

.column2 {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 0 0 50%; /* new */
}

 /* new */
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

 /* new */
.header form {
  width: 100%;
}

 /* new */
.header form input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
}

 /* new */
.header .add {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-row">
  <div class="box1">
    <div class="header">
      <!-- this field should be left -->
      <form>
        <input type="text">
      </form>
      <!-- this button should be left -->
      <button class="add">+</button>
      <!-- this button should be right -->
      <button class="edit">edit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column1">
      left column
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      right column
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <div class="header">
      <!-- this button should be left -->
      <button class="add">+</button>
      <!-- these buttons should be centered -->
      <button class="edit">btn1</button>
      <button class="edit">btn2</button>
      <button class="edit">btn3</button>
      <!-- this field should be right -->
      <form>
        <input type="text">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="column1">
      left column
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      right column
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-row">
  <div class="box3">
    <div class="header">
      header
    </div>
    <div class="column1">
      left column
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      right column
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box4">
    <div class="header">
      header
    </div>
    <div class="column1">
      left column
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      right column
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah. I see now. Using the boxes as flex containers. I did try that but I had flex set to 1. What is flex:0 0 50% doing?

Comment: Updated my answer to explain this.

Comment: It was actually the flex-wrap property on the boxes that made the change. If I set .column1 and .column2 to flex:1; I get the same result. But if I remove the wrap it doesn't work. Care to explain what the wrap is doing?

Comment: `flex-wrap` allows flex items wrapping (moving to the next line). Without this flex-items will always be on single line. Default value is `nowrap`. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use a column container for flex to work correctly.

Like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgdLLO

```
.col-container {
  display: flex;
}
```